# Asp.net MVC application using typescript and Phaser.io does not show images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, phaser-framework

I have a simple typescript game(using Phaser.io) that i what to run from an ASP.net MVC application in an MVC 5 View page with Layout (Razor)
I have added the view and the controller 
**/Views/Home/About.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="~/app.js"></script>

<div id="game"></div>
```

The game starts but it does not show any images. It looks like the reference to the image is wrong.
http://asskicker3.azurewebsites.net/Home/About

I reference the images as follows in the **app.ts**:

```
 preload() {
        this.game.load.image('background',"assets/background.jpg");
```

If i add an HTML page to the root of my folder it all work perfect.
http://asskicker3.azurewebsites.net/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <div id="game"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Answer:**
James Skemp solutions works. Just by adding the / it all works. Perfect!

Comment: Would you share a snippet with the section of code where you preload the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asset references are relative.

So if you look at the network tab in a browser you'll notice that it's trying to load the graphics relative to the URL. For example, http://asskicker3.azurewebsites.net/Home/assets/background.jpg

One way to fix this would be to change your `preload` so that the asset URLs are absolute instead of relative. So

```
this.game.load.image('background', "assets/background.jpg");
```

would become

```
this.game.load.image('background', "/assets/background.jpg");
```